# CSS making div get squashed

Tags: html, css

so this is my html

```
<div class="container midLevel" id="quizInfo">
    <div class="quizDetailsContainer floatLeft" id="quizDescriptionContainer">
        <text class="quizPresentationHeader" id="quizTitle">Test QuizTitle - replaced by handlebars</text>
        <text class="quizPresentationSubHeader" id="quizDescription">TestDescription- replaced by handlebars</text>
    </div>
    <div class="quizDetailsContainer floatRight" id="quizCreatorContainer">
        <a href="#" class="quizPresentationHeader" id="quizUserName">Test User Name</a>
        <div class="container lowLevel" id="quizUserContentContainer">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <text class="quizPresentationText">Test User Content</text>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <text class="quizPresentationText">Test User Content</text>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <text class="quizPresentationText">Test User Content</text>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my css-

```
.container{
    background:#F2F2F2;
}

.midLevel{
    background:#BDBDBD;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
}

.floatRight{
    float:right;
}
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Now, .container midLevel is getting 'squashed', as I can't see the background color and the border-bottom is appearing at the top. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `float: left` to `.container`.

Comment: @praks5432 - it works for the same reason @kennypu described, the container needs to be `float`ed in order for its `float`ed children to be considered part of its render flow. Without this, the children will not affect the height of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `<div class='clear'></div>` before the ending tag for .container.

The reason why it is shown to be 'squashed' is because when you use floats, whatever you float is not considered part of the regular render flow. so the .container treats the floated divs inside of it as if they're not there.